# In Swift 3, is it possible for a subclass to inherit defaults from its superclass?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In Swift 3 is possible to create a subclass that inherits default parameters from its superclass. E.g.,:

```
class ParentClass {
    let red: Double

    init(red: Double = 1.0) {
    self.red = red
    }  
 }

class ChildClass: ParentClass {
    let blue: Double

    init(blue: Double = 2.0) {
        self.blue = blue
        super.init()
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to create instances of ChildClass such that if I specify the value of red (e.g., `let foo = ChildClass(red: 10.0)` ) then I can set its value but if I don't then it's value will be the default (e.g., `let bar = ChildClass()` will have `bar.red = 1.0`).

Is this possible? The above doesn't work, but it's conceptually what I'd like. Additionally, I do not want to set the default value of red again in ChildClass (that defeats half the value of the superclass).

If something similar is better accomplished with structures or protocols that would work as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this works:

```
class ParentClass {
    let red: Double

    init(red: Double = 1.0) {
        self.red = red
    }
}

class ChildClass: ParentClass {
    let blue: Double

    init(blue: Double = 2.0, red: Double? = nil) {
        self.blue = blue

        if let red = red {
            super.init(red: red)
        } else {
            super.init()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize all properties when an instance of class is created. Actually `ChildClass` is like is:

```
class ChildClass: ParentClass {
    let blue: Double

    init(blue: Double = 2.0) {
        self.blue = blue
        super.init(red: <#defaultValue#>)  <-- default initializer
    }
}
```

There's not an `init(red:)` because `var blue: Double` won't be initialized when `init(red:)` called.

So if you want to use `init(red:)` in subclass, you must guarantee all your properties are initialized. You can try like this:

```
class ParentClass {
    var red: Double
    init() {
        self.red = 1.0
    }

    convenience init(red: Double) {
        self.init()
        self.red = red
    }
}

class ChildClass: ParentClass {
    var blue: Double
    override init() {
        self.blue = 2.0
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(blue: Double) {
        self.init()
        self.blue = blue
    }
}
```